# Banker's algorithm calculated time complexity

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory

The Banker's algorithm is used to determine if all requests for resources can be satisfied without leading to a deadlock.

**m is the total number of resources types**

**n is the total number of processes**

NEED is an array of size m * n, it defines pending requests for each resources type. E.g.: NEEDij = 2 means that process i is requesting for 2 items of resource j.

The algorithm is given below:

```
BOOLEAN function SAFESTATE is -- Determines if current state is safe
{ NOCHANGE : boolean; 
  WORK : array[1..m] of INTEGER = AVAILABLE;
  FINISH : array[1..n] of boolean = [false, ..,false];
  I : integer;

  repeat
    NOCHANGE = TRUE;
    for I = 1 to N do
      if ((not FINISH[i]) and
         NEEDi <= WORK) then {
         WORK = WORK + ALLOCATION_i;
         FINISH[i] = true;
         NOCHANGE = false;
      }
  until NOCHANGE;
  return (FINISH == (true, .., true));
}
```

My question is, how is time complexity 0(n * n * m)? More specifically, how does the m term enter the polynomial? Is it because we have to do an element-by-element comparison on a vector of length m?

Comment: Together with your comment on my just deleted answer it's really unclear what means what in this code. What are NEEDi, ALLOCATION_i and how is WORK assigned inside - element-by-element or some other way? Where does this code come from?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The below part introduces (n*m) time complexity

```
for I = 1 to N do // *n times
      if ((not FINISH[i]) and
         NEEDi <= WORK) then // *m times, if it's an array search
```

but it is also nested in a *repeat* loop. If that loop can run, in worst case, n times, then  the procedure has O(n*n*m) time complexity.

**Update:** I missed something,

```
WORK = WORK + ALLOCATION_i; // also O(m) operation, vectors addition
```

So, the code that executes in the *for* loop has O(m+m) time complexity.
Of course, O(m+m) = O(m) and the *final* complexity is O(n*n*m).

Comment: So the m is because of the <= operation on a vector of size m?

Comment: yes, that search/comparison has an additional O(m) time cost.